# Keep variable names after converting factors to numbers

Tags: r, printing, lapply, cat

I want to convert my categorical data to numbers, so I can use some packages.

The code under do that.

```
     data("iris")
     str(iris)
     must_convert<-sapply(iris,is.factor)       # logical vector telling if a variable needs to be displayed as numeric
     M2<-sapply(iris[,must_convert],as.numeric)    # data.frame of all categorical variables now displayed as numeric
     out<-cbind(iris[,!must_convert],M2) #output based on original dataframe
```

Problem is, for some variables there are 10 levels, and just converting to numbers is not enough because obviously manually checking which number is which factor isn´t very efficient.
I'm trying to convert the numbers to factor or list such as:

```
    iris_factors_to_numbers

    Species
    setosa         = 1
    versicolor     = 2
    virginica      = 3
```

Also, altough the iris data have only one categorical variable, mine have many.

Comment: Could you state which packages require this numeric conversion, please?

Comment: For example numbers2colors from WGCNA package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
keepvalues <- function(data) {
  filteredata <- data[sapply(data, class)=="factor"]
  result <- lapply(filteredata, function(x) paste0(levels(x), " = ", unique(as.numeric(x))))
  return(result)
}

keepvalues(iris)

$`Species`
[1] "setosa = 1"     "versicolor = 2" "virginica = 3"
```

Is something like this what you want?

Comment: This is awesome, works like a charm. For anyone who wants to do the same, remember that your variables MUST be in factor format, not character.